# How to create pie charts and present in html reports

Tags: java, charts, pie-chart

how to generate pie charts based on the data in the `XML` and present it using `html`.

`XML` contains steps related to test case steps and result of each steps.

The pie charts should show the total no of steps failed and passed.

I have no idea how to use charts in reports , tried to google it but could not get from where to start and also confused.

can anybody help me or guide me in the right direction.

forgot to mention that i am using  xslt to present data in html , how to do in that scenario.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try http://www.jscharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am biased towards [JfreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), pretty easy API to learn and one can create complex charts with some exposure to the API which is documented well enough.
In your case, the data source will be xml and output can be seen on the web.

Comment: forgot to mention that i am using  xslt to present data in html , how to do in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can try morris for generating chart

http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/

1. Try to extract data from xml file using DOM parser a good tutorial can be found here. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/
2. Use the extracted data in html page to make an array and render it using Morris.js

Comment if you need further clarification

Comment: forgot to mention that i am using  xslt to present data in html , how to do in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries available to draw charts. 
-[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) 
-[iReport](http://ireport.sourceforge.net) 
-[DataVision](http://datavision.sourceforge.net/) 
-[jsCharts](http://www.jscharts.com) 
-[highCharts](http://www.highcharts.com)

see [here](http://blog.dreamcss.com/dev-tools/charts/java-charting-and-reporting-tools/) for more